# How to enter copy mode on mouse scroll in tmux?

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal, tmux

The mouse scroll wheel does not work when not in copy mode. I'm not sure whether it is supposed to be working then? When in copy mode, the scroll wheel does work. The problem is that I still need to enter copy mode manually. Is it possible to enter copy mode upon mouse wheel activity? I am using gnome-terminal and the CVS version of tmux. These are my relevant settings:

```
set -g mouse-select-pane on
setw -g mode-mouse on
```

Comment: Are you expecting the wheel to scroll the tmux buffer, or the program's window? (vim, for example, uses the wheel to scroll the document.)

Comment: I am expecting to scroll the tmux buffer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In case people are still wondering, entering copy mode on mouse scroll is the default behaviour now in the development version of tmux.

Comment: Looks like it was added in tmux version 2.2 https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/ddbc4a0f6ca0c6486a038ce91971212785d44744