# Use terminal scrollbar with tmux

Tags: command-line, terminal, terminal.app, tmux

I know how to scroll in tmux using the keyboard, but I noticed that it looks like there's a way to use the [terminal scrollbar with GNU Screen](https://superuser.com/questions/138748/how-to-scroll-up-and-look-at-data-in-gnu-screen/177407#177407). Can this be done with tmux?

Comment: You can't really use the terminal scrollbar with GNU Screen. The scrollbar won't actually access Screen's scrollback buffer, but the terminal's, which means that scrolled-off lines from different Screen sessions get mixed up.

Comment: *[iTerm2](http://iterm2.com/)* has some future plans to [integrate with *tmux* ](http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/wiki/TmuxIntegration). Such integration seems likely to include using a native scroll bar to view the *tmux* history buffer.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This is possible in both GNU screen and in tmux and the workaround is similar: to fool the multiplexers into thinking that the terminal has no "alternate screen" mode (such as that used by pico, mutt, etc). This is accomplished by setting termcap commands for the session.

For GNU screen, put this in your `.screenrc`:

```
termcapinfo xterm*|xs|rxvt|terminal ti@:te@
```

and for tmux, add this to your `.tmux.conf`:

```
set -ga terminal-overrides ',xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'
```

The '`xterm*`' part of the command should be set to whatever your terminal-emulator is declared as. Some form of xterm is a good guess, but you can check yours on most sane *nix systems with:

```
echo $TERM
```

and this can usually be set in the preferences of your terminal program (ie: For Apple's `Terminal.app`, it's in Settings->Profile->Advanced (or Settings->Advanced->Emulation pre-yosemite) "Declare terminal as".

The end result is that the overflow ends up in the terminal's scrollback buffer instead of disappearing. Of course, since this is one static buffer, things will get messy as you switch between screen or tmux windows, but this is handy for quickly flicking up to see the output of an `ls` command or the such.

Comment: also, just saw http://superuser.com/questions/253414/how-to-enter-copy-mode-on-mouse-scroll-in-tmux , which works as described as another alternative.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on OS X...

Comment: Solution: https://gist.github.com/1297707

Comment: @Nick - Note that you're solving a different problem : adding mouse support to tmux. Might be a better solution for you, but it's different from using the native scrollback buffer. As long as your terminal emulator is properly defined the above will work on an y*nix, including OSX

Comment: That's correct. I was trying to get _some_ sort of scrolling in tmux, specifically under OS X. Just figured I'd post it here for posterity. Also, your solution probably didn't work for me because I wasn't reloading the .tmux.conf file (or tmux kill-server) (or C-b :source ~/.tmux.conf) (or C-b :set -g terminal-ov...) =)

Comment: Is `termname` a shell command? I get 'command not found' using bash on linux, I can't apt-get install termname, and I can't find any evidence it exists from googling around.

Comment: looks like that was a tcsh built-in. On bash you can use `echo $TERM`

Comment: this "overflow" works but shows up some odd unicode characters upon exiting tmux: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31790939/2668831

Comment: Note, I think you want to be sure mouse mode is off when using this approach. That way the terminal rather than tmux is doing the scrolling. So `set -g mouse-mode off` in tmux < 2.1 and `set -g mouse off` for tmux 2.1+.

Answer (score 8):

To enable scrolling, you can enable the *built-in mouse mode* in your `~/.tmux.conf` as follow:

```
set -g mode-mouse on
```

Comment: This is the old format. The new one simpler: `set -g mouse on`

Answer (score -1):

*My Env* :

linux fedora 29 x86_64 workstation, GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu), GNOME Terminal 3.30.3

*TO DO* :

1. See the version of tmux.

```bash
$ tmux -V
tmux 2.9a
```

2. Edit `~/.tmux.conf`

`set -g mouse on`

3. kill server

`$ tmux kill-server`

4. Re-run tmux

Then it shows terminal scrollbar in each tmux panel.

But if you want to paste text to the panel, you should use `ctrl shift v`.

Or see this [how-to-copy-and-paste-with-a-mouse-with-tmux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318281/how-to-copy-and-paste-with-a-mouse-with-tmux)

The above answers do not give step 3 and 4. I might be helpful to others.